# How to put this form on the right hand side of the nav tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to put `<nav>` and `<form>` side by side, in which `<form>` stands at the right hand side of `<nav>`. Is there a simple way to do that?

```
<h1>Demos</h1>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('kg') }}">kg</a>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('nu') }}">nu</a>
  </ul>
</nav>

<form class="search" method="post">

    <input name="search" type="text" style="margin:auto;max-width:500px" placeholder="Search ..." id="search" required>

    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap the elements in a div (or other containing element) you can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to align them:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container > * {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px dashed lightgrey; /* just to visualize the element boundaries */
  margin: 0.5em; /* provides space between */
}
```

```html
<h1>Demos</h1>
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('kg') }}">kg</a>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('nu') }}">nu</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <form class="search" method="post">

    <input name="search" type="text" style="margin:auto;max-width:500px" placeholder="Search ..." id="search" required>

    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How to make the space ratio of around 1:2, instead of the current 1:1 of the two sections? I mean I want the search box to take more space than the nav buttons.

Comment: Read up on [the basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). Specifically, [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis), and to a slightly lesser degree [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) and [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink).